# SQLite datetime comparison with 'now' in ISO8601

Tags: sqlite, date, datetime

I have datetime information stored in the format YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS in accordance with ISO8601 format. However I want to grab information from my SQLite database if the stored date is later than current datetime.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to implement:

```
SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE date > datetime('now')
```

The problem is that the SQLite function datetime('now') returns the date in the same format as the above but without the 'T' literal and so renders the stored datetime value which is in ISO8601 format incomparable to datetime('now').

Is there any way that I can make this comparison without changing the database values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could convert the database values into the same format:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE datetime(date) > datetime('now');
```

However, it would be a better idea to convert the comparison value into the database format (a direct access of the column value makes it possible to use indexes):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE date > strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', 'now');
```